# How to re-install ddd on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: software-installation, uninstall

From a couple of days ago, when I execute `ddd` (a graphic debugger using gdb inside), I only see this line below and doesn't give me the prompt.

```
GNU DDD 3.3.12 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu), by Dorothea L>>>
```

And the mouse cursor is a wait mark (sandglass).

After finding that my `~/.ddd` directory is messed (some configurations looked weird), I decided to reinstall `ddd`. And I did

```
sudo apt purge ddd
sudo apt install ddd
```

But it is the same! How can I get a fresh installation of `ddd`?

**ADD(solved)**
I found the ddd was just fine but my ~/.gdbinit file has some scripts for `dashboard`. I had installed dashboard the other day and it prevented gdb to work inside ddd. When I recover the ~/.gdbinit file, ddd started to work normally again. (I had backed up ~/.gdbinit file in the past just in case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most applications will never touch user config files inside `~`, even when doing an `apt purge`.

So in this case, you must manually back up your configuration (if you need some of it), and then remove the corrupt directory:

```
rm -R ~/.ddd
```

Afterwards, the application might generate new configuration next time it's run - or you could reinstall it as you already posted. In any case, this should reset everything to default.

Comment: Hi, I just found what my case was. The ddd was just ok, but the gdb working with ddd had some specificial features called 'dashboard' that interfeared with working with ddd. I'll add to my question.

Comment: Good you found the main issue!

Comment: I've chosen your answer to be the correct one because it seems to be the general answer if ddd was the problem. (though my case was a very special one.)